# SAS Check if folder is empty

Tags: directory, sas

I would like to ask how can you check using SAS, if the path/folder is empty?

If excel file exist in that path then import it to sas dataset.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
%macro isemptyfolder(folder);

    %let filrf=mydir;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf, "&folder"));
    %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));
    %let memcount=%sysfunc(dnum(&did));
    %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));
    %put 'number of members in folder ' &folder ' = ' &memcount;

%mend isemptyfolder;
```